# How to enable msaa on android app

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, ogre, msaa

I'm making app with android + [ogre3d](http://ogre3d.org). I'm using FSAA property, but there is an ogre [bug](https://ogre3d.atlassian.net/browse/OGRE-319): when use externalWindowHandle and fsaa together, fsaa doesn't work. I'm using  Surfaceview as a window for rendering.

Now i've found android developer option "Force 4x MSAA", and when i've turned on this option, my app started to work great, as I want! This option make all OpenGL es 2.0 apps working with MSAA. But it's not a good way asking users to turn on this option on their phones.

So, is there any way to make my app always use 4x MSAA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antialiasing in OpenGL ES 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035893/antialiasing-in-opengl-es-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is just about linux OS.

FSAA is old technology and ogre ignoring it. So, you can use MSAA or CSAA instead.

```
    ANativeWindow *nativeWnd = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);

    Ogre::NameValuePairList opt;
    opt["MSAA"] = "2";
    opt["externalWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString(
            reinterpret_cast<size_t>(nativeWnd));
    gRenderWnd = Ogre::Root::getSingleton().createRenderWindow("OgreWindow", 0, 0, false, &opt);
```